# getting error when adding facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-multidex

In my app when i added facebook sdk i am getting this error

Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.>    
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   
 org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
 Process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero     
 exit value 3
```

Previosly i was not getting this error.
After researching i enabled multidex to true

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   /* compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])*/
   /* testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    /*compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'*/
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0';
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'

}
```

Before setting `Multidex` to true i was getting

Please help me solving the issue.

```
exit value 2
```

and after setting it to true i am getting

```
exit value 3
```

Comment: use `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'`

Comment: any specific reasons??

Comment: Go through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started . I hope it will helps you .

Comment: Debug? Ok, close your Android Studio go to your app directory and delete `build` and `app/build` (don't miss anyone, there are two folders with same name). Then run Android Studio. It should recreate them. It should work

Comment: @piotrek1543 it should be acceptable

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I had some similar issues, so I think it's the easiest way to solve it

Comment: @SonaliPawar Did you solve yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya nah its still not working

Comment: @piotrek1543 i tried it but still no success

Comment: update your java to 1.7.65. You're using 1.7.05